# How to launch sh script with crontab?

Tags: python, linux, bash, ubuntu, cron

I have sh script that works perfectly if you launch it by yourself. But when I try to put it to the crontab nothing happens. My cron schedule expressions is

```
21 20 * * * bash a.sh
```

And this sh script includes

```
cd /home/ubuntu/currencies_datas_get && python3 AAVEUSDT.py &
cd /home/ubuntu/currencies_datas_get && python3 ADAUSDT.py &
cd /home/ubuntu/currencies_datas_get && python3 APEUSDT.py &
cd /home/ubuntu/currencies_datas_get && python3 ATOMUSDT.py &
```

It suppose to launch these scripts along and it really works if you try to type `bash a.sh` to the ubuntu console

Comment: That should work. What's happening instead?

Comment: There's no need to `cd` multiple times to the same directory.

Comment: Try redirecting `stderr` of the scripts to files so you can see if they're getting errors.

Comment: You don't know what directory `cron` is running in.  You need to specify the complete path to your script.

Comment: In which directory is `a.sh` located? Which user runs this cronjob?

Comment: @Cyrus /home/user

Comment: @Barmar nothing happens

Comment: @TimRoberts but I put the whole path to my python scripts

Comment: @Barmar those commands are all the background, so the `cd` is not effective for the script, only for the background block. But agreed, the `cd` could be factored out and run just once before the four background commands.

Comment: Try using `python3 AAVEUSDT.py 2> /home/user/AAVEUSDT.err &` to see the errors.

Comment: I wonder if cron kills children processes when the main script exits. Try adding `wait` at the end of the script, to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: The usual reason why something works differently in crontab is because it depends on environment variables that you set in your `.profile` or `.bashrc`, since these aren't executed by cron.

Comment: @Barmar so how to put bash directly to the crontab?

Comment: `21 20 * * * source .profile; source .bashrc; bash a.sh`

Comment: But it's generally better to figure out what the dependency is and just deal with that.

Comment: Append `>/tmp/log.txt 2>&1` to your cronjob and check this file when your cronjob has run.

Comment: Another suggestion is to simplify the script a bit: does it work if you run the four tasks one after the other not in the background? Once that works, you can go back to try to parallelize it the way you are doing with 4 background processes.

Comment: @aipz -- But you are ASSUMING that `cron` can find `a.sh`.  What if `cron` starts with the current directory in `/var/spool/cron/aipz`?  Unless your script is stored there, it will fail.

Comment: @TimRoberts everything stores in my user folder, I also worked with crontab to launch python scripts this path and it worked

Comment: @Cyrus I did it and nothing happened

Comment: How do you edit this cronjob?

Comment: @Cyrus 21 20 * * * bash a.sh >/tmp/log.txt 2>&1

Comment: I meant what command do you use to edit your cronjob?

Comment: @Cyrus `crontab s.cron`, I read it from file

Comment: I feel like I need to ask a dumb question: `21 20 * * *` will only run at 8:21 pm. While you're trying to debug it, you need to set the time to "in one minute" each time you edit, to see if it's doing anything. Otherwise, this line in your crontab will only get executed once a day, so doing any of the stuff we're suggesting here won't make a difference until the next time it's 8:21pm...

Comment: Was the file `/tmp/log.txt` created? If not, then your cronjob has not run.

Comment: @joanis it's just an example, I edit the expression every launch

Comment: Glad to hear it! :)

Comment: @Cyrus in /tmp?

Comment: Yes, this file: `/tmp/log.txt`

Comment: @Cyrus nothing appeared

Comment: This means that your cronjob is not executed at all. If the cronjob is executed, then at least an empty file should have been created.

Comment: _nothing happens_ is quite unlikely. I would have expected some error messages at least. For debugging, you could start it with the `-x` option to see what's going on.  BTW, the title of your question says that you want to run the script by `sh`, but your crontab runs it as `bash`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming a.sh is in $HOME, make your crontab

`21 20 * * * bash $HOME/a.sh`

Additionally, depending on where your `python3` binary is located, you may need to specify its full path, i.e., `/usr/bin/python3` in your script.

Comment: I'd just like to add that it's always a good practice to specify the full path of binaries inside the crontab and even scripts, as if the full path isn't specified, it may call another binary or script located in your path, this is a well known way for hackers to gain root privileges on a machine.

Comment: The default `$PATH` set by most cron daemons is `/usr/bin:/bin`.  This can be overridden at the top of your crontab with something like `PATH=/path/to/bin:/usr/bin`.  For security reasons, cron does not parse any system or user profiles or shell rc scripts.

Answer (score -2):

I suggest to add full path to `python3` in your script.